# Calculating time after another time - mysql datetime format

Tags: php, datetime

We've got a time in **MySQL datetime format**, like:

```
$time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$period = "+1 month";
```

Now we want to calculate '*N Days*' after this time, the thing is that I want the new calculated time also in **MySQL datetime format**, so I've created this function:

```
// From a date to period date based on date
function fromTime($time, $period){
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $time);
    $date->modify($period);
    return $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```

It works fine on my localhost since I'm using **PHP > 5.3**, but on my real server it's not working and I'm getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method DateTime::createFromFormat() in /home/blah/public_html/includes/functions.php on line 38
```

Line 38 is `fromTime` function.

How I need to change this function so it works also on **PHP < 5.3**

**UPDATE: OP is looking for solution that works in < 5.2 to be precise.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using DateTime class, you can use the older builtin date manipulation functions like `strtotime()`.

```
function fromTime($time, $period) {
    return date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($period, strtotime($time)));
}
```

Comment: Not working `Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in E:\wamp\www\blah\html\epay\back\test.php on line 11`

Answer (score 0):

I think everything is valid 5.2 except the `DateTime::createFromFormat`.  There is nothing non standard about the date format.  I'd say remove that line and instanciate the `dateTime` object like:

```
$date = new DateTime($time);
```

What PHP version do you need it to be compatible with?  < 5.2?

Comment: Yes needed to be compatible with PHP < 5.2

Comment: Well to state the obvious you should consider updating.  FYI, I updated question to reflect the version you are targeting.

Comment: @fi I'm on a shared hosting and there is nothing I could do about it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Pls Try It

```
$d = new DateTime( date("Y-m-d H:i:s") );
$d->modify( 'next month' );
echo $d->format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ), "\n";
```